# Set file's html reponse headers cache-control on IIS via powershell

Tags: http, iis, header, max, response

I'm trying to set cache-control: max-age on the http response header on IIS to a specific file. I'm trying to do that using a PowerShell script or a CMD command. can I do that? if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Too late to answer this question, might be helpful for those who are still looking for the solution.

I used "appcmd.exe" in Powershell.
Below is how I used in Powershell:

```
# path to appcmd.exe
$appCmd = "C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"

# Path to the folder where we want to set the cache max-age
# in this case its a "scripts" folder in "Default Web Site" site
$env:folderPathScripts = "Default Web Site/scripts"

# sets the max age to 2 days
& $appCmd --% set config "%folderPathScripts%" -section:staticContent -clientCache.cacheControlMode:UseMaxAge -clientCache.cacheControlMaxAge:2.00:00:00
```

or

```
#To disable the cache
& $appCmd --% set config "%folderPathScripts%" -section:staticContent -clientCache.cacheControlMode:DisableCache
```

I referred following links:

https://forums.iis.net/t/1174801.aspx?How+to+Remove+and+Add+custom+headers+convert+from+appcmd

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635852(v=ws.11).aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770661(v=ws.10).aspx